# Is there a way to reserve the order in which these charts are being display in the PowerPoint?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

The problem I am trying to solve is to automate the copy and paste from Excel to powerPoint which at the moment is time consuming because we deal with lots of charts in different sheets. So I did some research online to see if anyone else tried or succeeded at the task and here is the fruits of the research. However, it doesn't fully satisfy my purposes because even though it successfully copies and pastes in to powerpoint,  the ordering is messed up since it paste from oldest to newest.

I tried to used create a loop that starts in the last sheet to the first but having multiple charts per sheet still messed up the ordering in which I would like to see the charts displayed.

```
Sub chart_deliveryReverse()

    'declaring all of the objects that will be used
    Dim objPP, objPPFile, mySlide, myShape As Object
    Dim DestinationPPT, button As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim charts As Long
    Dim counter, counter1 As Integer
    Dim Xchart As Excel.ChartObject

    'Message Box with a message giving the user Feedback
    button1 = MsgBox("Creating PowerPoint")

    'assign the objPP to powerPoint App
    Set objPP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    'make it visible in the screen
    objPP.Visible = True

    'open specific powerPoint presentation
    DestinationPPT = "location of powerPoint"
    Set objPPFile = objPP.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)

    'Loop that start from beginning to ended
    For counter = 1 To Worksheets.Count Step 1

    'Commnented loop that starts at the last sheet to the beginning
    'For counter = Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1

        Set sht = Worksheets(counter)

        'Locate Excel charts to paste into the new PowerPoint presentation
        For Each Xchart In sht.ChartObjects

                'Copy each Excel chart and paste it into PowerPoint
                sht.Activate
                Xchart.Select
                ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

                'Customizes the powerPoint first number being where to start inserting slides and second number the layout
                Set mySlide = objPPFile.Slides.Add(2, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitle
                Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

                mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=6
                objPP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
                objPP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True

                mySlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Xchart.Chart.ChartTitle.Text

                'Align the lastest stored shape
                myShape.Left = 100
                myShape.Top = 50
                Next
            Next
    'Next

    ' Clean up
    Set objPP = Nothing
    Set objPPFile = Nothing
    Set mySlide = Nothing

End Sub
```

It opens up the specified powerpoint and populates it with the charts from the excel sheets

Comment: Try looping backwards? Change `For counter = 1 To Worksheets.Count Step 1` to `For counter = Worksheets.Count to 1 Step -1`. Or is the issue with the actual chart order on the worksheets?

Comment: I had already tried to loop backwards but it didn't quite work its the session of the code that says( 'Commnented loop that starts at the last sheet to the beginning
    'For counter = Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1) but that also didn't work but I just found the errors was the way the charts were being added to the powerPoint in the bottom of the code that says( Set mySlide = objPPFile.Slides.Add(2, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitle) while using the debugger and stepping through the code

Comment: Then I went online I found someone code that dynamically added sheets as they were bring select. The thread I found it on was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060188/how-to-dynamically-reference-powerpoint-slides-using-vba and changed my code to  Set mySlide = objPPFile.Slides.Add(objPPFile.Slides.Count + 1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitle and now it is working flawsly.